# Flask-Admin ModelView isn't handling foreign keys right (blank drop down)

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Flask beginner here. I have a little Flask app using the following model:

```py
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

class Answer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'))
    question = db.relationship("Question", backref="answers")
```

I fire up the admin using the following lines in my app:

```py
admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(ModelView(Question, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Answer, db.session))
```

Now in the create form for the answer model, I have a drop down box for question, but it's not populated properly:

[image: Answer create form with Flask-Admin]

The [quickstart guide](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/) doesn't cover models with foreign key relationships and although there are some [implementation examples available](https://github.com/MrJoes/Flask-Admin/tree/master/examples/sqla), they are not documented at all. I'm having a hard time figuring out what is really necessary here and how this works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to a friendly IRC user called *mattupstate*! The models need to have `__str__()` implemented:

```py
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, this solution didn't seem to work for me.
What I did to fix it was to override the model view, and explicitely remove the column I didn't want (in this case, the one concerned by the `relationship` annotation).

You can find my models.py and my overriden model views here: [github repo](https://github.com/jrm2k6/gallezi) or in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jrm2k6/8905880)